# Can the "simple" equation $e^x=\log(x)$ be solved using algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, closed-form

I came across this really simple-looking yet astonishingly hard problem to solve:
$$e^x=\log(x).$$

I tried to use Lambert-W function, but I cannot get it to the required standard form. Even Wolfram Alpha just provides the numerical approximation. Is this solvable using any special functions?

Comment: are you looking for complex roots? because i dont think there are any real roots

Comment: @UnsinkableSam yes, I am looking for complex roots. There would be no real solution because their curves wouldn't intersect.

Comment: Your question is the same as solving $e^x = x$, as taking log of both sides gives $\ln{x} = x$. Note that there are no real solutions as $e^x \ge x + 1 > x$. In terms of lambert-W function,

$$x = \ln{x}
\\-\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot \ln{\dfrac{1}{x}} = 1
\\\dfrac{1}{x} = W_k{(-1)}
\\\therefore x = \dfrac{1}{W_k{(-1)}} = -W_k{(-1)}, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: @Dstarred Wouldn't taking log on both sides result in x=log(log x)? How is it the same equation though?

Comment: Hi. $x=10^{(e^x)}$.

Comment: @BhuvanMS No, I intended $\ln{(e^x)} = \ln{x}$. $e^x = x$ and $\ln{x} = x \implies  e^x  = \ln{x}$. However, note that domain is not the same for both $\to$ what I intended from $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is that $k$ admits to only certain branches in integers. I do not know how many there are; most likely too many to write down. To find out which, you will have to test them individually.

Comment: @Dstarred Oh, now I understand that. Thank you for the solution. I totally didn't expect such a simple manipulation to solve the problem.

Comment: @Dstarred $e^x = x = \ln x \implies e^x = \ln x$ but $e^x = \ln x\ \ \not\!\!\!\!\implies e^x = x = \ln x$.

Comment: @Ennar Yes, I stated that the equation is valid for some branches (some integer $k$), not all of them.

Comment: @Dstarred I'm not sure what you mean by that, but if you have a solution for $e^x = x = \ln x$, then you surely have a solution for $e^x = \ln x$. The problem is that you are missing most of the solutions for $e^x = \ln x$.

Comment: In general, you can simplify the equation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ where $f$ is strictly monotonic by using symmetry in the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not algebraic, but maybe better than nothing. Assuming $\log=\ln$: In
$$
e^x=\ln x \tag1
$$
multiply both sides with $x$:
$$
xe^x=x\ln x \tag2
$$
and then apply Lambert-W on both sides using$^1$ $W(xe^x) = x$ and $W(x\ln x)=\ln x$:

$$
x=\ln x \tag 3
$$
Now $\ln (1/x) = -\ln x$ so we can divide by $x$ to get:

$$
-1=\frac1x\ln\frac1x \tag 4
$$
and then use $W(x\ln x)=\ln x$ again:

$$
W(-1)=W\left(\frac1x\ln\frac1x\right)=\ln\frac1x=-\ln x \tag 5
$$
hence
$$
x = \exp (-W(-1)) \tag 6
$$
Wikipedia mentions the approximated $W_0(-1) \approx -0.31813+1.33723i$.

Now this is a bit sloppy w.r.t. to which branch is being considered, but it should be clear now how $(1)$ can be approached.

---

$^1$See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Identities)

Comment: For one branch, $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$ are inverses of each other. This directly implies $e^x=x$ and $\ln(x)=x$ for this branch.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$, the equation doesn't have solutions because $e^x>\ln(x)$ for all $x>0$, as e.g. [the plot at Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+e%5Ex%2Cln%28x%29) shows.

$$e^x=\ln(x)$$

We see, your equation is an irreducible polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($e^x,\ln(x)$). We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (elementary operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.
I don't know if the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$x\to e^t$:
$$e^{e^t}=\ln(e^t)$$
$$e^{e^t}=t+2k\pi i\ \ \ (\forall k\in\mathbb{Z})$$

We see, we cannot solve the equation with Lambert W in the general case, but with Hyper Lambert W:

$$1=e^{-e^t}(t+2k\pi i)$$
$$e^{-e^t}(t+2k\pi i)=1$$
$t\to u-2k\pi i$:
$$ue^{-e^{u-2k\pi i}}=1$$
$$ue^{-e^{-2k\pi i}e^u}=1$$
$$G(-e^{-2k\pi i};u)=1$$
$$u=HW(-e^{-2k\pi i};1)$$
$$t=HW(-e^{-2k\pi i};1)-2k\pi i$$
$$x=e^{HW(-e^{-2k\pi i};1)-2k\pi i}$$

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the representations of Hyper Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

Answer (score 1):

We have $e^{e^x}=x$. Multiply by $e^x$ to get $e^x e^{e^x}=x\ e^x$. Apply $W$ to get $e^x =x$, so $-1=-x\ e^{-x}$ and $x=-W(-1)$. This only gives one solution because we are using the relation $W(z e^z)=z$ which is only valid in a certain region of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @IV_ I didn't make any change of variable. Take $e^x = \log x$ and apply $\exp$ on both sides.

Comment: @jagmath Oh I see. $e^{-W(-1)}=-W(-1)$. We can remove our both comments now.